# What does $\partial_j \partial^j u^i$ represent?

Tags: vectors, tensors

If $\partial_j u^i = \partial u^i / \partial x^j$ is a rank 2 tensor and represents nine different numbers, and $\partial_i u^i = \nabla \cdot \vec{u}$ contracts the upper and lower indices via a divergence and yields a scalar, what exactly does $\partial_j \partial^j u^i$ represent? (Please note that I am adopting a notation used in quantum field theory.)

Comment: That would represent the laplacian operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury, could you post an answer so that you can get credit for your comment?